# How to include a static Google map in a jade page

Tags: node.js, express, pug

I have made multiple searches but can't find a simple example of how to display a static Google map with some points plotted on it onto a jade/Express page.  Every attempt I make results in nothing being shown.  If I can just see how someone else has done this, I should be able to figure it out.  All I'm looking to do is plot some points on a map and display it on a web page.  Any pointers are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Google Static Maps are just plain old images. So include them like you would any other image.

```
doctype 5
html(lang="en")
  head
    title Example
  body
    h1 Google Static Map
    img(src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=Opera+House,Sydney+Australia&zoom=13&size=400x300&markers=-33.8565,151.2151&sensor=false")
```

The Google [Static Maps API V2 Developers guide](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/staticmaps/) can be found here.

If you want to build up the markers string server side and then output it client side, try this example.

```
res.render('template', {markers: '-33.8565,151.2151'});
```

and in the jade template

```
img(src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=Opera+House,Sydney+Australia&zoom=13&size=400x300&markers=#{markers}&sensor=false")
```

More details on the [markers parameter](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/staticmaps/#Markers) can be found in the guide.